# Unable to plot ggplot graph on Power BI

Tags: r, ggplot2, powerbi

I am trying to predict number of incident per day in Power BI R script. My data source is analysis services cube. I have executed below script but it is throwing an error:

```
Regressor = lm(formula = # Incident - Regular ~ Incident Date)
ggplot()+
geom_point(aes(x = dataset$Incident Date, y=dataset$# Incident - Regular), color ='red')+
geom_line(aes(x = dataset$Incident Date, y=predict(Regressor, new data = dataset)), color ='blue')+
ggtitle('Incident Count Prediction')+
xlab(' Incident Date')+
ylab('Number of Incident')
```

**Error**:

> R script error. Error: unexpected symbol in: "ggplot()+
>   geom_point(aes(x = dataset$Incident Date" Execution halted

Comment: Did you notice the space in `dataset$Incident Date`? ...and the `#` in `dataset$# Incident - Regular`? You are having issues due to your typos.

Comment: @KevinArseneau I appreciate your comment but this is how SSAS measure names comes up (i.e. with space) and # Incident Date is a measure name. Do you mean to say that R can not handle space between column name? Example: Do I have to change the column name to Incident_Date or IncidentDate instead of Incident Date?

Comment: You can use backticks (`) to enclose those column names, but it would be better practice to rename them.

Comment: @KevinArseneau PowerBi created dataset automatically when we select R script dataset <- data.frame(Incident Date,# Incident - Regular)

Comment: You can still rename the columns in the R script in PowerBI

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using *backticks* to enclose your string column names.

```
Regressor = lm(formula = `# Incident - Regular` ~ `Incident Date`)

ggplot() +
  geom_point(aes(x = dataset$`Incident Date`, y = dataset$`# Incident - Regular`), color ='red') +
  geom_line(aes(x = dataset$`Incident Date`, y = predict(Regressor, new data = dataset)), color ='blue') +
  ggtitle('Incident Count Prediction') +
  xlab('Incident Date') +
  ylab('Number of Incident')
```

Better yet would be to *tidy* your data first.

```
library(dplyr)

df <- tibble(
  incident_date = dataset$`Incident Date`,
  incident_regular = dataset$`# Incident - Regular`
)

Regressor = lm(formula = incident_regular ~ incident_date, data = df)

ggplot(df) +
  geom_point(aes(x = incident_date, y = incident_regular), color ='red') +
  geom_line(aes(x = incident_date, y = predict(Regressor, new data = df)), color ='blue') +
  ggtitle('Incident Count Prediction') +
  xlab('Incident Date') +
  ylab('Number of Incident')
```

Comment: Thanks for mentioning the correct way. I am executing now via dplyr library. While running Regressor =lm .... line I am getting this error Error in terms.formula(formula, data = data) : 
  'data' argument is of the wrong type

Comment: I think the error is because of the variable name df which is a function too. I renamed it to dfObject and now I am getting another error **Column `incident_regular` must be a 1d atomic vector or a list**, I believe it is may be because it is trying to create dataframe as a variable. I am not sure if I am correct.